# Product thumbnail disappeared after uploaded later in Heroku

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, paperclip, spree

I thought it all done setup Spree 3.1 in Heroku. But after successful upload product which shown thumbnail add to existing sample. The thumbnail later disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Pushed to run in Heroku only half way. Since Heroku is only read only storage when started. To upload pictures, it need additional services. In my case use AWS S3 from Amazon. And also need extra gems: Imagemagick, Paperclip to make thumbnails.